# Multiple rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

How to configure rails_admin for Multiple Admins.
How do i create Multiple admins using rails_admin gem.I created single admin for my rails application.I don't know how to create and configure another admin.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below steps to create new admin user.

1. Go to terminal where project folder resides run following command

   $rails console
2. You will get following console something like this

   1.9.3-p448 :001 >
3. Run following create statement on console

   admin = AdminUser.create! do |u|
       u.email = 'sample@sample.com'
       u.password = 'password'
       u.password_confirmation = 'password'
    end

   you can specify any email and password here

   This will create new admin user for Rails_admin

Comment: Ya I can able to create admin user.But I want to have multiple admin with seperate model view using rails_admin gem.How can i accomplish this.?    Thanks in advance